# Is there any way to sync my Outlook calendar to my Samsung Galaxy S without Kies?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, sync, calendar, samsung-kies, outlook

I am trying to sync my Outlook 2010 calendar to Samsung Galaxy S using Kies.  For some reason, it doesn't sync.

Kies has a nasty habit of hanging, so I would really like to use something else, if possible, instead of trying to understand why it doesn't sync to begin with.

Are there any tools out there that will sync the calendar directly to the phone without using Kies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about doing this over the air, rather than using a desktop client for the sync?

If you use Outlook, presumably your company uses Exchange for it's mail servers? If so, and if they allow Exchange Active Sync, and/or have Outlook Web Access enabled, then you could sync your phone's mail and calendar directly with them over the air.

The built-in Mail client can be used to connect directly with Exchange, or there are third party alternative Exchange clients like [Touchdown](http://www.appbrain.com/app/exchange-for-android-2-x/com.nitrodesk.droid20.nitroid), [Moxier](http://www.appbrain.com/app/moxier-mail-%28exchange-server%29/com.moxier.mail) or [K-9 Mail](http://www.appbrain.com/app/k-9-mail/com.fsck.k9)

Comment: My company does not allow Exchange Active Sync with Android phones, only with iphones and Blackberries.

Comment: Really? Mine specifically bans iPhones, but is looking at allowing Android 2.2+ & WM7 along with full support for Blackberries via our BES.

Answer (score 2):

You might give [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955) a try. It's a tiny application which will run on your Windows PC and synchronize your outlook calendar with googles calendar, so you'll have all your appointments always on your mobile. Works like a charm for me, and you'll not nitice it's even running.

Comment: My calendar has some data that I don't want to sync to Google for security reasons (the IT department where I work would not be pleased).  I want to copy the Outlook calendar directly to the phone.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the native Exchange app on your device. On my Galaxy S5 using Android 6.0, it's in Settings -> Account -> Accounts -> Microsoft Exchange Active Sync -> then I tap on the specific Outlook account I'm trying to sync.

Below is a screenshot of what it looks like on that next page. When I had this exact same problem, I found that "Sync Calendar" was not checked. I'm not sure where in my app updating or activities that this got unchecked, but putting this on immediately solved my sync problems.

For your device, it's probably buried somewhere in Settings as well, but it's not too hard to find once you get in there.

[image: Outlook Sync on Android 6.0 - Galaxy 5]