# Sync Outlook Calendar on my PC to Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, outlook

I use Outlook Calendar on my PC.  Can I sync it to Samsung Galaxy S4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP) for this.

> You can sync contacts, calendar, and tasks between your Microsoft®
>   Outlook and your device and vice versa.

**Related question:**

- [Is there any way to sync my Outlook calendar to my Samsung Galaxy S without Kies?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5421/is-there-any-way-to-sync-my-outlook-calendar-to-my-samsung-galaxy-s-without-kies/)